# Retrieve all records in single Query

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, dynamics-crm

I have created (1) 2 account (1st one will be parent of 2nd Account)
(2) Created 2 Contacts (Associate 1st Contact will be 1st account and 2nd contact with 2nd Account)
(3) Created one notes and associate it with Parent Account
(4) Created two notes and associate it with 2nd Contact

and now i want to  retrieve all records in single Query..

I tried but not getting result..

```
var fetch = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>" +
                  "<entity name='account'>" +
                    "<attribute name='name' />" +
                    "<attribute name='primarycontactid' />" +
                    "<attribute name='telephone1' />" +
                    "<attribute name='accountid' />" +
                    "<order attribute='name' descending='false' />" +
                    "<link-entity name='contact' from='parentcustomerid' to='accountid' link-type='inner' alias='bd'>" +
                    "<attribute name='fullname' />" +
                      "<link-entity name='annotation' from='objectid' to='contactid' link-type='inner' alias='be'>" +
                        "<filter type='and'>" +
                          "<condition attribute='subject' operator='not-null' />" +
                        "</filter>" +
                      "</link-entity>" +
                    "</link-entity>" +
                  "</entity>" +
                "</fetch>";

 EntityCollection Coll = CrmConn.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch));

                foreach (Entity acunt in Coll.Entities)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name of Account: " + acunt.GetAttributeValue<string>("name"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Name of Contact: "  +acunt.GetAttributeValue<string>("fullname"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Name of Notes: " + acunt.GetAttributeValue<string>("subject"));
                    //Console.WriteLine("contact: ", Coll.Entities[]);
                 }
```

It's show only account name not showing notes and contact

Comment: In 1 single query you won't be able to retrieve annotations as well.
Reason: Your 2nd account does not have annotation and your 1st contact does not have annotation as well.
when you are linking annotations with contact you will only retributive linked records with contact and that too only 2nd contact as your link type is Inner.

Instead loop through your account and contact records and retrieve linked Notes

Comment: Thank you for your response but through this  query ,contact also not retrieve..Actually i print result inside console..

Comment: Check my Answer below, It shall helps. If it does please mark it as answer.

Comment: foreach (Entity acunt in Coll.Entities)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name of Account: " + acunt.GetAttributeValue<string>("name"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Name of Contact: "  +acunt.GetAttributeValue<string>("fullname"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Name of Notes: " + acunt.GetAttributeValue<string>("subject"));
                  }   //This one is correct way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK use the below query to retrieve only Accounts and it's Related Contacts. I could retrieve accounts and it's related contacts.
Now take those accounts and it's ID and use 2nd query to fetch Notes (Annotations)
Same thing you will do for Notes.

```
<fetch>
  <entity name="account" >
    <attribute name="name" />
    <link-entity name="contact" from="parentcustomerid" to="accountid" link-type="inner" >
      <attribute name="fullname" />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Query to Retreive Notes:

```
<fetch>
  <entity name="annotation" >
    <attribute name="filename" />
    <attribute name="documentbody" />
    <attribute name="isdocument" />
    <link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="objectid" link-type="inner" >
      <filter type="and" >
        <condition attribute="accountid" operator="eq" value="AccountGuid" />
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Example with C# code

```
string fetch = @"  
   <fetch>
  <entity name='account' >
    <attribute name='name' />
    <link-entity name='contact' from='parentcustomerid' to='accountid' link-type='inner' alias='Contact' >
      <attribute name='fullname' alias = 'Contact.Fullname' />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch> ";

           EntityCollection Coll = CrmConn.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch));

                foreach (Entity acunt in Coll.Entities)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name of Account: " + acunt.GetAttributeValue<string>("name"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Name of Contact: "  + acunt.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("Contact.Fullname").Value);
                 }
```

Comment: How can i print all these result  inside console?

Comment: EntityCollection Coll = CrmConn.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch));

                foreach (Entity acunt in Coll.Entities)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name of Account: " + acunt.GetAttributeValue<string>("name"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Name of Contact: "  +acunt.GetAttributeValue<string>("fullname"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Name of Notes: " + acunt.GetAttributeValue<string>("subject"));                   
                 }

Does this not work for you??
This is the correct way.

Comment: did this helped??

Comment: No its not working...it only print account name not contact and notes..

Comment: Name of Account: ACC_048
Name of Contact:
Name of Notes:                                        //This is the output

Comment: I have updated my answer to retrieve Alias values i.e Contact fullname

Comment: Can i also fetch Notes in this query, Notes is also related to Account..Because It's not retrieve notes only retrieve account and contacts.

Comment: You got Account ID's and ContactId's now based on this you could do something like below
<fetch>
  <entity name="annotation" >
    <attribute name="filename" />
    <attribute name="isdocument" />
    <attribute name="documentbody" />
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition attribute="objectid" operator="in" >
        <value>AccountGuid1</value>
        <value>AccountGuid2</value>
        <value>AccountGuid2</value>
      </condition>
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>

Comment: string fetch = @"  
   <fetch>
  <entity name='account' >
    <attribute name='name' />
    <link-entity name='contact' from='parentcustomerid' to='accountid' link-type='inner' alias='Contact' >
      <attribute name='fullname' alias = 'Contact.Fullname' />
    <link-entity name='annotation' from='objectid' to='contactid' link-type='inner' alias='Notes' >
      <attribute name='subject' alias = 'Notes.Subject' />
    </link-entity>
    
  </entity>
</fetch> ";//Right?

Comment: Nope you are trying to mix 2 entites with Notes. I think we already mentioned that you need to fetch seperately for Account ID's and then for Conact ID's.
If you link Account and Contact and then Notes it wont as few of your Contact Record does not have Notes attached.
Refere to my 2nd query and c# code.

Comment: string fetch = @"  
   <fetch>
  <entity name='account' >
    <attribute name='name' />
    <link-entity name='contact' from='parentcustomerid' to='accountid' link-type='inner' alias='Contact' >
      <attribute name='fullname' alias = 'Contact.Fullname' />
    <link-entity name='annotation' from='objectid' to='contactid' link-type='inner' alias='Notes' >
      <attribute name='subject' alias = 'Notes.Subject' />
      </link-entity>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch> ";This is working for Contact but not Account and my assignmentc is retrieve all records in single Query

Comment: both contact are linked with notes and only one account is linked with notes